# Show list of SQL value in html FullCalender page from flask

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, flask, fullcalendar

I use .py for get value from sql:

```
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    cur.execute(
        'SELECT sname FROM `sessioncreate` WHERE sessioncreate.sdate = %s AND `ownerId` = %s',
        (today_date, str(check_id)))
    user = cur.fetchall()
    for row in user:
        a = (" | ".join(row))

    events = [
        {
            'sess_name': a,
            'date': today_date
        }
    ]

    if check_isadmin == 1:
        return render_template('dashboard.html', events=events)
```

my .html page:

```
 <script>

      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
      var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        events : [
        {% for event in events %}
        {
          title : '{{event.sess_name}}',
          start : '{{event.date}}',
        },
        {% endfor %}
      ]

    });
    calendar.render();
  });

</script>

<div id='calendar'></div>
```

my query result:

[Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVZ3E.png)

Problem is in html page is show only the second result of query 'aaab', i want to show both.

[Html Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xLa2.png)

How can i achieve that?

Comment: You're only assigning `events` once as far as I can see, instead of making an array and appending to it inside the `for` loop. Therefore it will only use the values as they were set after the loop ran for the last time. I'm not a python expert but I'm sure you can Google how to create a list or array with python and add to it

Comment: No problem. Did you understand what I mean?

Comment: @ADysin Yes i understand what do you mean, thank you i change code and work well.

Comment: You should write the final solution as an answer below then (it's fine to answer your own questions!) then others with similar issues can search for it and upvote it, if it's useful to them :-)